# Best way to iterate through a file with new line separators

Tags: c, file, file-read

Let's say I want to read a file where each line has a string, and when there is a new line or the end of the file, I print the number of characters read. For example,

```
abcdf
asd

sdfsd
aa
```

This would print (counting new line characters at the end of each string):

```
10
8
```

(there is no new line at the end of the last line, so we get 8 instead of 9). I could do something like this

```
FILE* f;
// ...
int charCount = 0;
char line[20];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, f))
{
    if (strcmp(line, "\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", charCount);
        charCount = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        charCount += strlen(line);
    }
}
printf("%d\n", charCount);
```

Notice that I have to repeat the printf after the loop ends, because if I don't, I wouldn't print the last value (because the file reached the end and there is not a new line at the end). For a `printf`, this is not that bad, but if I had something more complicated, it would result in a lot of repeated code. My workaround is putting what I want inside a function and just call the function after the loop, but I feel like there has to be a better way. Is there a better way to parse through a file like this? Preferably not character by character in case I have some formatted data that I need to use `fscanf` with.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm sorry but I don't see how that solves the problem. I tried and got the same result.

Comment: If it's available to you, POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) gives you the length of each line.  It looks like you stop accumulating the length when you get a line back of length 1 (containing only a newline), or when you get `-1` returned (since the function formally returns `-1` and not `EOF`, even though `EOF` is usually `-1` — `EOF` can be any convenient negative number).

Comment: There's some confusion.  It looks like you want to generate output when 2 consecutive newlines are seen, not when a newline is seen.  So I wonder about your sample output and whether or not your input has a newline at the end of the file or not.  The sample input you give appears to have a newline at the end of the file; just not 2.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But my problem is the check after the end of the file. I'm already doing a check to see if the line contains just ```"\n"```.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is — `getline()` tells you how many characters it read, or `-1` if it did not read any.

Comment: @WilliamPursell the file does not have a new line at the end. My example file is: ```abcdf\nasd\n\nsdfsd\naa```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move your `fgets` call into the body of the `while` loop, while checking its result in the loop condition and in the printing condition. It should be properly initialized before the loop to a non-NULL value.

```
FILE* f;
// ...
int charCount = 0;
char line[20];
char *result = line;
while (result)
{
    result = fgets(line, sizeof line, f);
    if ( result == NULL || strcmp(line, "\n") == 0 )
    {
        printf("%d\n", charCount);
        charCount = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        charCount += strlen(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I tried to come up with something like this but couldn't do it. I tried to do something like this, but the problem remained ([this](https://pastebin.com/yn0cwteY) is how I was doing it). I was almost there I guess. Anyway, thanks for the help. One more thing: could you explain what ```while(result)``` means? If the pointer is not NULL, the loops runs?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much the same as in your code - it loops while `fgets` returns non-NULL

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it the caveman way...

```
char ch;
int i = 0;
FILE *fp = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");

while (feof(fp) == 0)
{
    i++;
    if ((ch = fgetc(fp)) == '\n')
        printf("%d\n", --i), i = 0;                 
}

if (i > 1) printf("%d\n", --i);
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Suggest reviewing [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2410359)

Comment: @chux I read a lot of "what can happen" in that post, but haven't seen it happen in 35 years of checking EOF.  I'll just keep bangin' out caveman code that works 99.973% of the time, refuse to conform and leave the spaceship code to the "developers".  Thanks for the concern though.